# Horse object inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, junit

I have a class Horse shown below I have to make it that the Horse object does not take a driver that is not a Perso object, and it inherits the Vehicle class and cannot have an engine that is not itself. I am failing test4, test1, and test2 in the Junit test posted under my code. I belive the issue Lies in how i am handling the set engine and set driver methods specifically. is there a specific way i need to set the methods up in this case?

**horse.java**

```
public class Horse extends Vehicle implements Engine {
public Horse(Driver driver){
super(driver, null);
super.setEngine(this);
}
//@override
public void setEngine(Engine engine){
if(engine == null){
    super.setEngine(this);
}
else if(engine instanceof Horse){
    super.setEngine(engine);
}
else{
    throw new IllegalStateException();}
}

//@override
public void setDriver(Driver driver){
    if(driver instanceof Person){
        super.setDriver(this);
}
    else{
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
    //@override
    public int getForce(){
        return 746;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
    if(other instanceof Horse){
        if(((Horse)other).getForce() == this.getForce()){
            return true;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int compareTo(Engine o) {
        int force = this.getForce() - o.getForce();
        return force;

    }
}
```

**Vehicle.java**

```
abstract class Vehicle{
Engine engine;
Driver driver;
public Vehicle(Driver driver, Engine engine){
}
public Engine getEngine(){
    return engine;
}
public void setEngine(Engine aEngine){
    engine = aEngine;
}
public Driver getDriver(){
return driver;
}
public  void setDriver(Driver aDriver){
driver = aDriver;
}

public boolean equals(Object other)
{
if(other instanceof Vehicle){
if(((Vehicle)other).getEngine().equals(this.getEngine())){
    return true;
}
}
return false;
}
public int compareTo(Engine o) {
int force = o.getForce();
return force;

}
}
```

**Engine.java**

```
public interface Engine extends Comparable<Engine>{

int compareTo(Engine o);
public int getForce();

}
```

**junit test**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class HorseTest {

@Test
public void test0_HorseIsAVehicleAndAnEngine() {
    Horse horse = new Horse( new Person( 55 ) { } );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", horse instanceof Vehicle );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", horse instanceof Engine  );
}
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void test1_HorsesCannotBeRiddenByAnyDriverOtherThanPeople_NEW() {
    new Horse( new Driver() { } );
}
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void test2_HorsesCannotBeRiddenByAnyDriverOtherThanPeople_SET() {
    Horse horse = new Horse( new Person( 42 ) { } );
    horse.setDriver( new Driver() { } );
}
@Test
public void test3_AHorseIsItsOwnEngine() {
    Horse  horse  = new Horse( new Person( 99 ) { } );
    Engine engine = horse.getEngine();
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", horse == engine );
}
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void test4_HorsesCannotHaveAnEngineThatIsNotItself() {
    Engine anEngine = new Engine() {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Engine o) {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public int getForce() {
            return 0;
        }
    };
    Horse horse = new Horse( new Person( 24 ) { } );
    horse.setEngine( anEngine );
}
@Test
public void test5_AHorseReceivingNullOrItselfAsEngineSetEngineToItself() {
    Engine engine;
    Horse  horse  = new Horse( new Person( 99 ) { } );

    horse.setEngine( null );
    engine = horse.getEngine();
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", horse == engine );

    horse.setEngine( horse );
    engine = horse.getEngine();
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", horse == engine );
}
@Test
public void test6_HorseHasEquals() {
    Engine  a, b;
    boolean actual;
    // equal to itself
    a      = new Horse( new Person( 21 ));
    actual = a.equals( a );
    assertTrue ( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // equal to another horse (regardless of driver)
    a      = new Horse( new Person( 42 ));
    b      = new Horse( new Person( 24 ));
    actual = a.equals( b );
    assertTrue ( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to null
    actual = a.equals( null );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to some other object
    actual = a.equals( "84" );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to some other object
    actual = a.equals(  48  );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
@Test
public void test7_HorseHasCompareTo() {
    Horse a, b;
    int   actual;
    // equal to itself
    a      = new Horse( new Person( 52 ));
    actual = a.compareTo( a );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", actual == 0 );
    // equal to another horse (regardless of driver)
    a      = new Horse( new Person( 9 ));
    b      = new Horse( new Person( 8 ));
    actual = a.compareTo( b );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", actual == 0 );
}
}
```

Comment: This code is poorly designed. In this situation, inheritance does not make sense. Redesign the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Why does horse need to implement engine, but vehicle doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `test1`, you're not calling anything that would check to see if the driver is a person.  You call the `Horse` constructor, and that uses `super(driver,null)` which calls the `Vehicle` constructor, but at no point are you calling the `setDriver` method, which is the only thing that would check `driver instanceof Person`.  (Furthermore, the `driver` just gets thrown out.  Neither the `Horse` constructor nor the `Vehicle` constructor saves it anywhere.  The `Vehicle` constructor should probably have this:

```
this.driver = driver;
this.engine = engine;
```

)

I haven't tried your code, but the reason for the `test2` failure might be that `setDriver` actually throws `IllegalStateException` but you're telling JUnit to check for `IllegalArgumentException`.  Same thing for `test4`.  Fix those first, and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I was writing the same about test 1. And the exception's type mismatch in tests 2 and 4 makes a lot of sense. Just +1.

Comment: ok managed to fix every thing but test1. i sort of understand what your saying but am confused as to how i would change my code to implement it

Comment: @Darksole The simple solution is to have the `Horse` constructor do the same check and throw an exception if it fails.  (There would be a little bit of duplicated code, and I'd put the "driver check" in a method so that it would be in just one place.  But for now, start by getting it to work.)